# Trouble with objects and Pointers

Tags: c++

```
vector < Shape* > shapes;

void createScene()
{

 image = QImage(width, height, 32); // 32 Bit
 Color amb(0.1,0.1,0.1);
 Color difCoef(0.75,0.6,0.22);
 Color spec(0.5,0.5,0.5);
 double shine= 3.0;
 Sphere *s = new Sphere(Point(0.0,0.0,-5), 100.0, amb, difCoef, spec, shine);
 shapes.push_back(s);

}




int main(){

 // initialize glut
 init(); 
 createScene();
 Shape *x = shapes[0];
 cout << x->shine << endl;
}





class Shape
{
 public: 
 Shape() {}
 ~Shape(){} 
 Color ambient;
 Color dif;
 Color spec;
 double shine;
 virtual bool checkIntersect(Point p, Point d, Point &temp) = 0; // If intersects, return true else false.
 virtual Point getNormal(Point intPt) = 0; // Get the normal at the point of intersection
 //virtual void printstuff() = 0;

};
```

When it prints out shine, i get a value of zero? Why is that?

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more of your code....

Comment: where is your shapes[] defined?

Comment: What library is 'Shape' from?  Is it a class you designed or that came from a library?

Comment: Color amb(0.1,0.1,0.1); 

is not the way to declare a new object and pass in values to the constructor. You need

Color *amb = new Color(.1,.1,.1);

Comment: As long as the new Sphere is copying the constructor arguments, the presented way is fine. Using new would only mean having to worry about extra memory management.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You push *pointers* into the container `shapes`. You are retrieveing object *values* from the container. If you are using a standard container, this cannot and will not compile. If you are using some weird homemade container, you have to tell us what it is. Without more information about `shapes` there's no way to say anything meaningful about your question.

Comment: @confusedEj, it would really help to see the constructor of `Sphere`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) occures (since you'r using a Shape object and assigning to it). What you would want to do in order to preserve polymorphism is use a pointer or a reference. In this case I would use a pointer:

```
Shape *x = shapes[0];
```

If shapes is an odd container which does de-reference (this is what i understand from your code) then I would use a reference:

```
Shape &x = shapes[0];
```

You could use a const reference, but it isnt mandatory here since your object is not a temporary one by any means.

Btw, hasn't anybody told you globals are a bad practice?

Answer (score 2):

This code cannot be compiling.  If you have defined a container for `Shape*` as is implied by the lines

```
Sphere *s = new Sphere(Point(0.0,0.0,-5), 100.0, amb, difCoef, spec, shine);
shapes.push_back(s);
```

Then, you could not be retrieving a `Shape` from `shapes` as in

```
Shape x = shapes[0];
```

Comment: Unless he's using public inheritance and is accidentally slicing his Sphere instance into a Shape instance.

Comment: @Joe: What does "public ineritance" have do do with it? In the first case it is a container of pointers, in the second - of objects themselves. The OP's code does not make any sense, as Dave correctly noted.

Comment: It could be some custom container doing de-reference under the hood. I wouldn't be that surprised if the supplied code didn't compile, though. My answers covers both situations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Shape is an base class of Sphere and others, you should not make a copy of it. Currently, you are (probably) slicing the object which is actually a Sphere by making a copy of its Shape base part.

Taking a pointer or a reference to the Shape object, as others have suggested, should solve your problem.